# JMockit With Chain Methods

Tags: java, testing, mocking, jmockit, chain

I am having difficulty understanding how to properly mock chain methods with Jmockit

so here is an example of a chain method i would want to test

```
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll()
        .and()
        .httpBasic().disable()
        .csrf().disable();
  }
```

My undestanding currently is to manually specify each method in the Expectation and return a mock. Then do this for each step. Like below

```
new Expecations(){
http.authorizeRequest()
result = mockedRequests;

mockedRequest.anyRequest()
results = mockedAnyRequest;

//etc


}
```

My question is there a better way of doing this? I feel like this is alot of extra code for a simple test. P.S This is for JMockit 1.8

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's a trivial test that will exercise the code and give you full coverage.

```
@Test
public void testConfigure(
    @Mocked final HttpSecurity http)
    throws Exception
{
    config.configure(http);
}
```

That said, if you need to do more exotic stuff like confirm 'disable' was invoked, or the order of calls (which, implementation-wise, is important), this test cannot (easily) do.  To go there, you wind up building those chains in the expectations like you were showing - PITA.  If someone wanted such higher degree of testing, I'd argue that would be the job of a higher level system or integration test, not a unit test though.